# How to externalise spring application configuration using config server?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, config

I have written my own config server to centralise configuration management and exposing application configuration using APIs. Now i want to consume configuration properties from spring and spring-boot applications. But i am not able to figure out the correct way for that. I tried placing my config server client code to listen for application context start event and reading configuration from config server. But i am not able to inject this configuration into other beans.

How can i read application configuration from config server (using rest client) and inject this read config to application environment for further processing ?

Answer (score 0):

create an application that for config and your application

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableConfigServer
public class ConfigApplication  {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(ConfigApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

application.yml in config server

```
spring:
  cloud:
    config:
      server:
        native:
          search-locations: classpath:/shared
  profiles:
     active: native


security:
  user:
    password: pass

server:
  port: 8888
```

and create shared folder in src/main/resources/shared and your-service.yml like this

```
spring:
    security:
        basic:
            enabled: false

server:
    port: 8083
```

maven pom.xml in config server

```
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.1.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>Camden.SR5</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-config-server</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <finalName>config</finalName>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

in your-service spring boot application add /src/main/resources/bootstrap.yml

like this

```
spring:
  application:
    name: your-service
  cloud:
    config:
      uri: http://localhost:8888
      fail-fast: true
      username: user
      password: pass
```

and add this dependency to your service

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-config</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

first run config server and then your spring boot service

Comment: Hi Ali, i am not using spring-cloud-config server, but i have mine own config server and config-client.

Comment: why you are not using cloud config? you want to write one project like cloud config :D

Comment: There are few requirements which required me to write my own config serve, sure i dont like re-inventing the wheel, but yes this gives me more control over data models, code and functionality.